# Sending JSON via python to a external PHP listener

Tags: php, python, json

The issue I am having is a bit of a strange one but I'll explain as best I can.

At the moment, I run a series of scripts that produce a JSON file which stores details about a server room. This JSON file is then passed to a PHP listener which populates a database by parsing the JSON and extracting information.

The JSON posts to the database fine when using the mozilla add on "Poster" however whenever I run this from my VM and try and automate it I get this error -

**Fatal error**:  Only variables can be passed by reference

I also get a bunch of these errors

Illegal string offset 'acronym' in **C:\xampp\htdocs\globalHEC\php_http_request\hecdashboard.php** on line **98**

The sending python method:

```
def send_json_results(result_dict, server_ip, server_port):
'''Send the json file usinf http to the listening monitoring server'''
    url="http://%s:%s/globalHEC/php_http_request/hecdashboard.php?id=ni100&type=json" %(server_ip, server_port)
    data=json.dumps(result_dict)
    req = urllib2.Request(url, data, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    resp = f.read()
    print "Results sent to %s with response: %s" % (server_ip, resp)
```

Segment of PHP listener code:

```
$locres = $mysqli->query("SELECT loc1.Id FROM `location` AS loc1 WHERE loc1.Timestamp = (SELECT MAX(loc2.Timestamp) FROM location AS loc2 WHERE loc2.Id = loc1.Id LIMIT 1) AND
                    loc1.Id = '".$jsonArray_new["acronym"]."' AND 
                    loc1.Continent= '".$jsonArray_new["continent"]."' AND 
                    loc1.Country = '".$jsonArray_new["country"]."' AND
                    loc1.City = '".$jsonArray_new["city"]."' AND
                    loc1.Latitude = '".$jsonArray_new["latitude"]."' AND
                    loc1.Longitude = '".$jsonArray_new["longitude"]."' AND
                    loc1.CellVersion = '".$jsonArray_new["cell_version"]."' AND
                    loc1.NumberOfCells = '".$jsonArray_new["number_of_cells"]."' LIMIT 1;");

//any changes or fresh Location, so add it 
if ($locres->num_rows == 0) { 
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO location (Id, Continent, Country, City, Latitude, Longitude, CellVersion, NumberOfCells, Timestamp) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)')) {
$res = $stmt->bind_param("ssssddsis", $jsonArray_new['acronym'], $jsonArray_new['continent'], $jsonArray_new['country'], $jsonArray_new['city'], $jsonArray_new['latitude'], $jsonArray_new['longitude'], $jsonArray_new['cell_version'], $jsonArray_new['number_of_cells'], $jsonArray_new['timestamp']);
        $finishings += (int)$stmt->execute();
        $finishingQuota++;
        }
}
```

jsonArray_new is initialized as follows:

```
$file_content = file_get_contents('php://input');
echo "try to create file: ".$folder.$location.".json";
$numbytes = file_put_contents($folder.$location.".json", $file_content) OR EXIT("ERROR: Creation of ".$location.".json was not possible.");
print "$numbytes bytes written\n";
//} 
$jsonString_new = $file_content;

$jsonArray_new = json_decode($jsonString_new, true);
```

Comment: Both errors are **PHP** errors. You'll have to show us the PHP code too. The Python code looks entirely sane.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/cbA9NPhF - Pastebin link of the segment of PHP code which seems to cause the error.

Comment: Please [Edit] your question to add that, don't put it in comments.

Comment: Sorry thats it amended now.

Comment: No, you need to put code **here**. Make your question stand on its own without external links.

Comment: The segment of code on the php listener is too large to put in the comments?

Comment: Also, the code doesn't show how the `jsonArray_new` was created. Obviously it doesn't have such keys as 'acronym', etc. Show us the code where it was populated.

Comment: He doesn't mean the comments, put it in the question. Instead of just pasting a link to the code, paste the code itself in the question.

Comment: @McCourt2364: it isn't too large for inclusion in your question.

Comment: Ahh okay! Sorry my bad! Still new to stack overflow!

Comment: Your `jsonArray_new` is wrongly initialized. It seems to be a string rather than a dict. Show us the code where it is initialized.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to check if your json is created correctly. After `json_decode` call, the resulting array might consist of nested arrays like

```
$jsonArray_new = array (
    array(
        'your JSON data here as key=>value pairs'
    ),
);
```

hence prohibiting you from getting array values by key.

Before using decoded data I'd recommend simple `empty()` check as decoding might fail, and `$jsonArray_new` might have `false` as a value.

Side Note: your code requires refactoring. Too many potentinal points of failure.

Comment: Hi @s3nt1nel, I found out my error. the PHP code was sound, but the python code was causing the error. It was sending in a already parse json object and the error lay that I thought it was a string so I was trying to json parse an already json object. If that makes sense!